# Invalid email address with an underscore

Tags: customer-portal

I tried to create a client that has an email address with @flightcare_multiservices.com for some reason it doesn't seem to work. i don't know if it because of the underscore or not ? did anyone faced similar issues ?

[image]

Comment: email address format is `test@test.com` you need to add `@`

Comment: I've updated the question now

Comment: Greg you email address is wrong.. email correct format is `sometext@anothertext.domain`. Your email can't start with @

Comment: Right that is just to protect their identity as they might wish not to publish their email address. its testname@flightcare_multiservices.com

Comment: So then don't use `apex:inputField` here use `apex:inputText`

Comment: It's when i Try to create a new Account objects all the fields are standard and they usually work  except for this one. It might be something to do with the underscore

Comment: ohh this is standard page... Then don't use email field instead text field. because email field will validate the email in client side (before saving).. so text field will work for you..

Comment: Sorry it's a Standard Contact Object. All im doing is creating a new contact and one of the fields is Email. We need to put it there to work with everything else. When i Create a new portal user and put in the email username with a domain that has an underscore it doesn't seem to work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue (4+ years old) in the platform - see [Allow underscores "_" in email domain fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Z5bLAAS).

Add your vote and comment but you will have use a workaround (e.g. alternate text field) for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like this is not going to happen anytime son since there is an industry standard RFC1123 that prohibits underscore (_) in the email domain.
https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/underscores-not-allowed-in-fqdns.htm
It is working fine having underscore before the @.

Comment: +1. A good discussion is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it